# long poll implementation on every request to the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Below is the code to implement long poll.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  cattr_accessor :acArray
end

ApplicationController.acArray = []

class HelloController < ApplicationController
  def initialize
    ApplicationController.acArray << self
  end

  def index
    ApplicationController.acArray.each_with_index {|val, index|
      if index == 1 # only on second request serve the first request, until then hold the object in memory
          val.render :text => ApplicationController.acArray.length
      end
    }
  end
end
```

The problem is the first request gets failed immediately with the message

Template is missing
Missing template hello/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/myhome/tmp/chat/app/views"

How to delay the rendering and not let the rails search for the view file and not return failure status

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
    until ApplicationController.acArray.length > 1 do |process|
    end
    ApplicationController.acArray.each_with_index{|val, index|
        if index == 1
            val.render :text => ApplicationController.acArray.length
        end 
    }
`
```

Comment: Just curious, have you tried printing the value of the length of the acArray immediately before the error occurs?

Comment: I placed **p ApplicationController.acArray.length** before **next** in the else block which prints 1 before error

Comment: This blocks the server. also until does not take process arg.